# How to query using a different field other than the PK (primary key) field in DetailView

Tags: python, django, sqlite, listview, detailview

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^employee/(?P<emp_no>[0-9]+)/$', TitleDetail.as_view(), name='e-title'),  
    # /employee/10001/
    ]
```

views.py

```
class TitleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Title
    pk_url_kwarg = "emp_no"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TitleDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title_list'] = Title.objects.filter(emp_no_id=self.kwargs['emp_no'])
        return context
```

models.py

```
class Title(models.Model):
    emp_no = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()
```

sample data in database:

```
id          title            from_date   to_date     emp_no_id 
----------  ---------------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           Senior Engineer  1986-06-26  9999-01-01  10001     
2           Staff            1996-08-03  9999-01-01  10002
```

why does it give me

> PAGE NOT FOUND: No title found matching the query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In fact, you don't have to override `get_object` method, what you need to do is just to define a proper slug field(not `pk_url_kwarg`) like this:

```
class TitleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Title
    slug_field = "emp_no"
    slug_url_kwarg = "emp_no"
```

And [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/711123e1cdaf3b08c876c045d8d38decdc7a63d3/django/views/generic/detail.py#L33) is the source code if you'd like to see what has happened behind.

Comment: I got this error message, "Generic detail view TitleDetail must be called with either an object pk or a slug"

Comment: @JasonTK Sorry, I just missed one line in the sample, please add `slug_url_kwarg = "emp_no"` as well. Answer updated.

Comment: Awesome. I used the get_object() and it works too, but I'm using your code, so much easier. Thanks so much.

Comment: Good, then maybe you could accept this answer and mark it as `useful`, so others could get benefits as well :)

Comment: Is that by clicking on the checkmark to turn green? sorry as you can see i'm new to stackoverflow,

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `get_object()` method to do whatever you want:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    queryset = self.get_queryset() if queryset is None else queryset
    return get_object_or_404(queryset, emp_no_id=self.kwargs['emp_no'])
```

In case you haven't seen it before, see the [`get_object_or_404()` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404).